# What is the performance impact of domEvents: true in HammerJS?

Tags: hammer.js

The hammerJS docs mention the following:

```
  domEvents: false
  Let Hammer also fire DOM events. This is a bit slower, so disabled by default.
```

What type of measurable effect is "a bit slower"? How does it impact performance? and under what circumstance?